# Array literal or string split?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Lets say you needed a hardcoded list of strings (the question here is not whether or not you should hard-code things).

Is there a reason to prefer this:

`var things = 'a b see'.split(' ');`

over this:

`var things = ['a', 'b', 'see'];`

Comment: Only thing I can think of is it would be easier to copy/paste in new data for debugging purposes.

Comment: Maintainability, however both are poor form, the data should be coming from HTML.

Comment: I can't imagine any reason to *prefer* the first approach. The question seems like it has no basis.

Comment: @zzzzBov Err, what? HTML is for presentation, not data storage, and there is no guarantee that there *is* HTML involved. This could be server-side JavaScript.

Comment: @meagar, CSS is for presentation (view), HTML is for content (model), JS is for interaction (controller). Make good use of `<template>` elements and `[data-*]` attributes and you won't need many hard-coded strings in JS at all.

Comment: @zzzzBov Again, you're *assuming* the presence of HTML. And sorry, but *no*, CSS is for applying visual styles to your markup, but it's your markup that you're presenting to the user. Users don't *see* CSS, they *see* the combined result from applying CSS *to your markup*. Trying to equate CSS/HTML/JavaScript to MVC indicates *deep* lack of understanding of what "MVC" is.

Comment: @meagar, For clarification, I was referencing the MVC architecture that is front-end development, and not an MVC framework where HTML CSS & JS are bundled together and called a "view". As comments are not the correct place for these sorts of discussions, please feel free to send me an email if you'd like to discuss this further.

Comment: @zzzzBov I don't agree that this is poor form. If you look at the jQuery source they define their events with "blur focus...".split(" "). https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event/alias.js#L6 Imagine if the user had to define the events jQuery allowed in some HTML markup. This has nothing to do with presentation.

Comment: @CraigMacGregor, jQuery chooses to use a number of techniques that are not generally good ideas, but those techniques are typically chosen explicitly for performance and portability. An analog to your argument would be to say that it's a good choice to skip the closing `</html>` tag because google did it on http://google.com/

Comment: @zzzzBov I agree they focus on perf over readability. But in this case I think it's an elegant and clean solution instead of adding repetitive code for each event. If that's a counter to my argument you are saying that anything google does is not in good form? So minification, css sprites are all bad form and should be avoided?

Comment: @CraigMacGregor, to me, your argument was ["jQuery does it, so it must therefore be good practice"](https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/genetic). I'm refuting that argument, which does not logically equate to ["Everything that google/jquery/\[other popular group\] does is not in good form"](https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/strawman).

Comment: again, these extended discussions really don't belong in chat, so if anyone has further arguments against my (probably naïve) statements, please please please [send me an email](http://stackoverflow.com/users/497418/zzzzbov).

Comment: @zzzzBov Fair enough. That wasn't what I meant to imply. Don't do what jQuery does just because they do it without understanding why. I've used that technique many times where I choose readability over perf.  Iincluded the jQuery link just as a reference since IMO it's a very clean example showing this approach (subjective I know).

Comment: I understand the opinion-based nature of this question - it is primarily why I asked it. After encountering the code, I was unable to convince the developer with the (seemingly obvious)facts of preferring #2 (maintainability, clear intent, etc), and was hoping to find more here.

Answer (score 3):

Pros of first approach:

1. Easier to refactor data from code. (String is not language specific)

Pros of second approach:

1. Less prone to error (what if your string has a space in it?)
2. Easier to format automatically (can and probably should separate each string by newline)
3. Easier to get data from alternate sources in the future.
4. Signals intent more clearly
5. Tiny bit more efficient